# Routing attribute broke Elmah url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, elmah

Recently I make use of routing attribute in a MVC5 website that also make use of Elmah module but since a long time. Once I finished to implemente all routing, Elmah url has been broken and are not longuer found. To reach and display Elmah errors the website use an iframe :

`<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/elmah.axd")"></iframe>`

So I'm not able to find any solution to make it back. Errors are still logged and I can open them from a directory, but got a page not found from the url above.

Thanks,

David

### Edit

Here the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="local" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="CachedExpiration" value="00:05:00" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>-->
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /></modules>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /><handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
...
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
<!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
  <security allowRemoteAccess="false" /></elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->  
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location></configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share your web.config file?

Comment: @ThomasArdal, I just added it.

Comment: Which ELMAH packages are you using and in which versions?

Comment: @ThomasArdal: The version of elmah and elmah.corelibrary are 1.2.2.

Comment: Try adding the following to your RouteConfig: routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: It's already there :(

Comment: And to understand you correctly. The request for /elmah.axd returns a 404?

Comment: @ThomasArdal, yes exactly

Comment: I'm running out of ideas then :( I did check your config using the [ELMAH Configuration Validator](https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator) and everything looks fine. If you create a new empty MVC project and install the same packages, does it work then?

Comment: You had a good idea!! I got the answer thanks to you, I'll post it in few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, I had to add the Elmah.Mvc package in addition to these packages :

```
<package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

To my project and removed the .axd string to the iframe url like this:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/elmah")"></iframe>
```

Everything works fine now with the routing attribute activated.